# Get validation failure reason for JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a form where I post some data using ajax. Error message back is `validationfailed`. The reason for that scenario is that I am expecting a number and the user typed in a character.

I can't get this error message to display in . It's as if validation has failed but no reason is given. I tried `<p:message>` or `<h:message>`. I can print a diagnostic message by checking  `rendered="#{facesContext.validationFailed or not empty facesContext.messageList}"`

How can I see or show that the validation has failed since

```
<p:inputText value="#{bean.vacancies}"
             id="numberWorkersWidgetId"
             maxlength="2"
             />
```

, was not a number?

Message Panel is as follows

```
<h:panelGroup id="messagePanelId">
   <p:messages  showDetail="true" closable="true" autoUpdate="true" globalOnly="true">
      <p:effect event="load" type="pulsate" delay="800" speed="2000">
          <f:param name="times" value="1"/>
      </p:effect>
   </p:messages>

   <p:messages id="workDaysMessageId" showDetail="true" closable="true" autoUpdate="false" globalOnly="false"                                     redisplay="false">
    <p:effect event="load" type="pulsate" delay="800" speed="2000">
          <f:param name="times" value="1"/>
    </p:effect>
 </p:messages>
```

Comment: Just to exclude the obvious, is the `<p:message(s)>` component itself updated during ajax request? If not, also not after adding `autoUpdate="true"` to it? Nonetheless, in the future please always post problematic code in MCVE flavor. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: I see the XML component being updated but there is no message displayed since update itself does contain any messages.

Comment: You have one `p:messages` with `autoUpdate="true"` AND `globalOnly="true"` (so that won't show any validation messages) and you have one with `autoUpdate="false"`  and `globalOnly="false"`, but you don't explicitly update that, so it won't show any messages either. Hence no messages would be shown...